# Stopping Java Quartz Scheduler

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I built a cron scheduler to run every 5 seconds just to test if it works.

It is working perfectly but how can I stop it? It is running even if I stop the server.

```
Trigger t1 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("ReminderSchedulerTrigger", "group1")
                .withSchedule(
                        CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?")
                        .inTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"))
                )
                .build();

    Scheduler sc = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
    sc.start();
    sc.scheduleJob(job, t1);
```

I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, use below command to grep your project jar file

```
user@user:~$ ps aux | grep YourProject.jar
```

Then you will see something like this

```
user@user:~$ ps aux | grep xxx.jar
user      7438 40.1  3.3 4493040 271968 pts/7  Tl   11:06   0:10 java -jar xxx.jar
```

use command `kill -9` to kill the process

```
user@user:~$ kill -9 7438
```

Answer (score 1):

**On unix/linux:**

On a command prompt type

```
ps -ef | grep jar-file-name
```

This will list the process details of your running jar. The second column of the result is the process id.
For example the process id of the following line is 2571

```
501  2571  1   0 11Dec17 ??  0:00.81 /usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

You can then kill the process with the following command

```
kill -9 2571
```